# How to duplicate rows in pandas, based on items in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
COL     data
line1   [A,B,C]
```

where the items in the data column could either be a list or just comma separated elements. Is there an *easy* of way of getting:

```
COL     data
line1   A
line1   B
line1   C
```

I could iterate over the list and manually duplicate the rows via python, but is there some *magic* pandas trick for doing this? The key point is how to automatically duplicate the rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.explode()` option. Refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). I believe this is exactly the functionality you need.

Answer (score 8):

You could write a simple cleaning function to make it a list (assuming it's not a list of commas, and you can't simply use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)):

```
def clean_string_to_list(s):
    return [c for c in s if c not in '[,]']  # you might need to catch errors

df['data'] = df['data'].apply(clean_string_to_list)
```

Iterating through the rows seems like a reasonable choice:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame([(row['COL'], d)
                       for d in row['data']
                       for _, row in df.iterrows()],
                       columns=df.columns)
Out[11]:
     COL data
0  line1    A
1  line1    B
2  line1    C
```

*I'm afraid I don't think pandas caters specifically for this kind of manipulation.*

Comment: where does "row" and "row['COL']" come from?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp inside the list comprehension `for _, row in df.iterrows()`. The _ is the row's index, the row is the row of df as a Series.

Comment: This did not work for me as written; I needed to switch the two `for`statements: `[(row['COL'], d) for _, row in df.iterrows() for d in row['data']]`.

Comment: @AndyHayden, please correct your answer. For me also only RafG answer works.