# Append Dictionary Elements into an Empty Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have data in a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
queryName   Market  tags    categoryDetails
dummy_query (dummy_market)  dummy_market    dummy_tag   [{'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '2892695401'}, {'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '21892718'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'Location', 'parentId': '21221517840', 'id': '229565351'}]
dummy_query (dummy_market)  dummy_market    dummy_tag   [{'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '2892659'}, {'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '2892667'}, {'name': 'irrelevant_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '268415777'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'Location', 'parentId': '21221517840', 'id': '2565351'}]
dummy_query (dummy_market)  dummy_market    dummy_tag   [{'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '2892695401'}, {'name': 'irrelevant_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '268415777'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'Location', 'parentId': '21221517840', 'id': '229565351'}, {'name': 'Consideration', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2203873', 'id': '2203874'}]
dummy_query (dummy_market)  dummy_market    dummy_tag   [{'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '2892695401'}, {'name': 'irrelevant_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '268415777'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'Location', 'parentId': '21221517840', 'id': '229565351'}]
dummy_query (dummy_market)  dummy_market    dummy_tag   [{'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '21892718'}, {'name': 'irrelevant_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '268415777'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'Location', 'parentId': '21221517840', 'id': '229565351'}]
dummy_query (dummy_market)  dummy_market    dummy_tag   [{'name': 'relevant_data', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '289245228', 'id': '2892659'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'Location', 'parentId': '21221517840', 'id': '229565351'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2203873', 'id': '2203880'}]
```

I need my dataframe to have an additional, fifth column which will contain all the name keys with the elements called "relevant_data" of each row. These datapoints are selected based off of the parentName. If parentName = 'relevant_scrape', select "name."

How should I go about doing this? Here is my code so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep = '\t')
for row in df.categoryDetails:
    if isinstance(row, str):
        list_dicts = json.loads(row.replace("'", "\""))
        for each_dict in list_dicts:
            if each_dict["parentName"] == "relevant_scrape":
                df['fifth_column'] = each_dict["name"]

df.to_csv('output.txt', sep = '\t')
```

(Note: my original data is a bit messy and couldn't be rendered as JSON until I replaced its quotation marks with double quotation marks. Hence the json.loads call.)

This produces for me a dataframe with a fifth column, but it inserts the same exact "name" element in each row. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `df['fifth_column'] = each_dict["name"]`, which sets all values in the `'fifth_column'` column to the same value each iteration, since pandas' operations are column wise by default.

Maybe you should try the following snippet:

```
def extract_details(row):
    # your parsing logic.
    if isinstance(row, str):
        list_dicts = json.loads(row.replace("'", "\""))
        all_relevant_data = []
        for each_dict in list_dicts:
            if each_dict["parentName"] == "relevant_scrape":
                all_relevant_data.append(each_dict["name"])
        return ','.join(all_relevant_data)
```

and then you could do:

```
df['fifth_column'] = df.categoryDetails.apply(extract_details)
```

Comment: I got: "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment" when I replaced column with row.

Comment: This executed, but all the data in that column (fifth column) is being duplicated from the first piece of "relevant_data." Any ideas?

Comment: This is what the code you posted does. all the first dicts have name=relevant_data in the data.

Comment: I had to change the data for privacy reasons. Each "relevant_data" point can be one of ten different strings. I need the code to apply each snagged data point onto the fifth column and also only to those rows which have that data- right now this code actually appends it to every single row. Thank you again! Upvoting your answer and comments.

Comment: No problem :). if you want all the 'relevant_data' fields you might want to keep a list (and append relevant data from each dict to it) and then return the list in the inner function. i'll edit the answer again

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Actually....what if I wanted, instead of having two "relevant_data" fields in the fifth column separated by a comma, to have only one in that column per row and then duplicate the row so that the second "relevant_data" point was in the fifth column cell for that row?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058147/flattening-an-array-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1