# Split row that have multiple value in a cell and append back to the data list

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have this dataframe, in which some values in `Postcode` may have more than 1 postcode. What I try to do is to split the row that have multiple postcode and then append back into the dataframe.

I already get the list of index that have multiple postcode using following code;

```
index_list = df_selangor[df_selangor['Postcode'].str.contains(' ')].index
```

This allow me to create new dataframe and then split the value in `Postcode` like this;

```
df_selangor_split = df_selangor.copy()
df_selangor_split = df_selangor_split[df_selangor_split.index.isin(index_list)]
df_selangor_split['Postcode'] = df_selangor_split['Postcode'].str.split()
```

[image]

However, I stuck after this step. I not sure how to split it again so that the `Area` is copied and have only 1 postcode.

Comment: This may be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15954301/7067946. Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(row['Area'], row['Postcode'].split(','))
         for _, row in dfx.iterrows()])
```

Basically, we are iterating each row and splitting the postcode column for each area and then concatenating it.

Comment: this code help this problem... but it kinda mess with my DataFrame layout.. Thanks

Comment: kinda mess? Can you explain? Also, you can set the new dataframe to a different variable.

Comment: well the code put the `Postcode` value as index thus when I reset the index of the dataframe, the `Postcode` become the first value... it is ok, I just need to rearrange the column back... no biggie